# Saving a .sol file from one instance and using it as WARM_START for another instance on PYOMO

Tags: cplex, pyomo

Dears,

I´m running several scenarios (instances) of an AbtractModel on PYOMO.

For each of these instance, I would like to record its solution for further use as a WARM STARTER for another instance solve.

I´m very confused on how to accomplish this through Pyomo. How should I proceed?

Should I write a '.sol' file after the solve and use it as the warm start file? If so, how is the pyomo syntax for controlling the directory and filename of the written sol file? and how is the syntax for reading it back on solving the other instance?

Thanks,

PS: I´m using CPLEX as solver via SolverFactory()

Comment: The SOL file is a CPLEX-specific file format. Given that pyomo is supposed to be a generic modeling wrapper around different solvers it seems unlikely that you will find support for what you are looking for. With that said, I am not a pyomo expert, so perhaps I am wrong. However, if you want to take advantage of CPLEX-specific features you are probably better off using the CPLEX Python API directly or docplex.

Answer (score 0):

let me change a bit the [zoo and buses example](https://medium.com/@alexfleischer_84755/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-part2-python-java-c-cc04558e49b5):

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('cplex')

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.nbBus = pyo.Var([40,30], domain=pyo.PositiveIntegers)

model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = 500*model.nbBus[40] + 400*model.nbBus[30])

model.Constraint1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = 40*model.nbBus[40] + 30*model.nbBus[30] >= 300)


model.nbBus[40]=8
model.nbBus[30]=1

results = opt.solve(model,warmstart=True)

print("nbBus40=",model.nbBus[40].value)
print("nbBus30=",model.nbBus[30].value)
```

gives

```
nbBus40= 6.0
nbBus30= 2.0
```

Comment: But is it possible to store those values into a file and then use this file for initializing another diferent model?

Comment: Hi then you could write your own read / Write Code or rely on the docplex api https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=41691ae0-9179-4c5f-86cc-5f389cdfc394