# solve iteratively with cplex?

Tags: optimization, while-loop, cplex, pyomo

I'm trying to solve an optimization program with cplex and pyomo through python. I want to solve it iteratively where at each iteration I change the time period where the variables are binary.(for example in the first iteration i solve the model with the variables keep binary in the first 100 hours while for others hours the variables are continuous, so at second iteration will be binary only the variable for the next 100 hours,and so on...). I'm trying with a while cycle, where inside it the solver works for differents times ranges with a for cycle(I can add the code if required). But It seems too slow, maybe my cycle is not correct.There is a faster way to write this and solve a lot of time a model iteratvely?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

what could make the code faster is to use warm start instead of starting from zero in the search. See [Saving a .sol file from one instance and using it as WARM_START for another instance on PYOMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296799/saving-a-sol-file-from-one-instance-and-using-it-as-warm-start-for-another-inst)

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('cplex')

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.nbBus = pyo.Var([40,30], domain=pyo.PositiveIntegers)

model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = 500*model.nbBus[40] + 400*model.nbBus[30])

model.Constraint1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = 40*model.nbBus[40] + 30*model.nbBus[30] >= 300)


model.nbBus[40]=8
model.nbBus[30]=1

results = opt.solve(model,warmstart=True)

print("nbBus40=",model.nbBus[40].value)
print("nbBus30=",model.nbBus[30].value)
```

Within docplex CPLEX API you can do some [incremental changes](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooincremental.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

# original model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

#now 350 kids instead of 300

print()
print("now 350 kids instead of 300")    
    
mdl.get_constraint_by_name("kids").rhs=350;
mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

# no more than 4 buses 40 seats

print()
print("no more than 4 buses 40 seats")


mdl.get_var_by_name("nbBus40").ub=4
mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

#change the objective so that cost for 40 seats is 450
#and remove the limit on the number of buses 40 seats

print()
print("change the objective so that cost for 40 seats is 450")
print("and remove the limit on the number of buses 40 seats  ")  
    
mdl.get_var_by_name("nbBus40").ub=1000
mdl.set_objective("min",nbbus40*450 + nbbus30*400);
mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Comment: I shouldn't create an istance of the model?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the usual `pyomo.environ.SolverFactory` approach, this create an `instance` of your model, then generates a `.lp` file, to be send to the solver via shell commands, the solver solves the problem and generates a `.sol` file and it is loaded back to the model.  To solve the same problem with some incremental changes in the model, you can use the [Persisten Solver Interface](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/persistent_solvers.html). This creates a `gurobipy` or `docplex` (for `gurobi` and `cplex` solvers, respectively) model from the `pyomo` model, then it may be faster and better to use this approach. There is also de [APPSI interface](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/appsi/appsi.html) but i have never worked with it.

Comment: I shoud use these incremental changes to update the variable value at each iteration?

Comment: I don't fully understand what is your full problem. It will be better if you edit your question and show us a minimal reproducible example. If your problem is that model construction is slow, you can use some approaches to boost the speed, if the slowness is coming from the solver, you will need to see if your using the correct formulation for your problem.

Comment: first iteration: binary variables for period 0-100 hours, continuos for 101-8760 and solve
second it: fix values of binary variables found before, binary variable in period 101-201,continuous in 202-8760,solve again
And so on..                                                                                                        It's a while cycle where at each iteration i change the domain of variables for some time periods. My question is how i can fix the values found in the previous iteration? I'm not sure about this. Maybe persistent solver that you said is the right way.

Comment: You can do that. Fixed variables are not longer variables, but params, therefore, solving time will be reduced with each iteration. After solving the model, you can fix any `x[k]` `Var` with `model.x[k].fixed = True` and change the domain of any  `x[k]` `Var` using `model.x[k].domain = pyo.Binary`. When you're done fixing and changing your model, you can just resolve again with the approach that you prefer. I don't know your model, but certainly modeling a whole year in hourly basis will take a while for each solving

Comment: i create an instance with persistent then i create the cycle:while n<N                           for t in range(1,100): model.x[t].domain = pyo.Binary                                                for t in range(100,8760): model.x[t].domain = pyo.Reals                              opt.solve(the instance)                                                                           model.x[t].fixed = True for t in range(1,100)                                                                                       Sorry for all these questions but i'm new in python and i'm stuck with this.